# Mocking pymongo for unit testing

Tags: django, mongodb, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pymongo

I have a simple application in Django REST, I am using Pymongo to connect to MongoDB.
My directory structure is like this:-

```
appauth/
├── apps.py
├── controllers.py
├── databases
│   ├── initialize_databases.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mongo_connector.py
│   ├── redis_connections.py
│   ├── redis_connector.py
├── handlers
│   ├── handlers.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── helpers
│   ├── helpers.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── permission_loader.py
├── __init__.py
├── model
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── users.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
```

I have initialised my Mongo connection in mongo connector and imported it to initialise_databases. Then I am importing it from there throughout my application as and where I need it.

My main problem is, when I want to unit test, how do I specifically mock the db code.

For ex:

```
def login()
    //code//
    last_filled = db.UserSurvey.find_one({'user_id': user_id})
    //code//
    db.UserSecurityData.count({'user_id': user_id})
    user_role = db.User.find_one({'_id': user_id})
```

In my tests, if do something like

```
@patch('pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one')
@patch('pymongo.collection.Collection.update')

def test_03_validate_login(self, mocked_update, mocked_find):
    mocked_find.return_value = user_findone_return 
    //user_findone_return is a variable
    mocked_update.return_value = user_findone_return
    res = self.usr_obj.validate_login(user.email, user.password)
    self.assertEqual(res["gender"],'Male')
    self.assertEqual(res["password_expires_in"],45.0)
```

The test works perfectly with correct return values.But this seems to mock 
**all** find_one calls. My question is how to I mock different collections and their queries.

My DB settings:-

```
MONGO_URL = "mongodb://" + MONGO_HOST + ":" + MONGO_PORT + "/" + 
MONGO_DB
client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URL)
db = client.core
```

I have tried `@patch('pymongo.core.UserSurvey.find_one')`
and similar iterations. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone else is also stuck on same problem!
The patch should be same i.e.

```
@patch('pymongo.collection.Collection.update')
```

To give different values for same mock object one can use .side_effect to mocked object.
FOr ex, to mock the update function to return multiple values, pass a the 'mocked_update' obj to the function and then in the function

```
mocked_update.side_effect = [val1, val2]
```

This will effectively pass val1 the first time update is called and val2 the second time.